# « Rendre le sens » et « render the meaning »

Tags: traduction, anglais

> Our sincere thanks to M Joe Smith for his efforts to *render* in French the *meaning* of the texts.
>
> Nos sincères remerciements à M Joe Smith pour ses efforts visant à rendre en français le sens des textes.

Peut-on employer le verbe **rendre** pour traduire correctement le verbe anglais **render** dans le contexte de cette phrase (*render the meaning*) ?
Est-ce mieux d'utiliser *traduire* ?

> Nos sincères remerciements à M Joe Smith pour ses efforts visant à traduire en français le sens des textes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oui, ce verbe signifie « traduire » dans le contexte des correspondances d'une langue à l'autre.

Comment: Sauf qu'on rend une idée ou un concept, un sens etc., et qu'on traduit un texte, mais on ne rend pas un texte (sauf si c'est un devoir…).

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Il n'y a aucun mal à faire votre propre réponse en reprenant la mienne, qui n'est pas un travail auquel je puisse attacher une bien grande exclusivité ; je veux dire qu'un peu tout le monde peut dire cela.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Si je comprends bien tu veux dire que rendre ne peut traduire render dans ce contexte ?

Comment: @dimitris Non, c'est une plaisanterie (« rendre un devoir » pour « remettre un devoir  au professeur »).

Comment: Merci, c'est noté.